# Can we say "issues are not an obstacle"?

Tags: grammaticality, plural-forms

I just read an answer on Stack Exchange containing the following sentence.

> If these issues are not an obstacle, then […].

Is this grammatically correct? I think it should be rewritten as follows:

> If these issues are not obstacle**s**, then […]."

Comment: In any context I can imagine, it would be just as acceptable (and mean the same) if you wrote *If these obstacles are not an issue...* In fact, Google finds 21 occurrences of that form, whereas the only instance of *If these issues are not an obstacle* is actually the SE answer OP refers to. (FWIW, there are ***three*** instances of *If these issues are not obstacles*).

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical, but each gives a different emphasis. The first suggests that the issues collectively constitute an obstacle, the second that each issue is an obstacle in itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use both the sentences.

On the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, there are three sentences using "are not an obstacle" and one sentence using "are not obstacles."

> Many family service agencies operate on a sliding scale fee schedule, so finances **are not an obstacle**.

> And then others that are skewing more to a younger demographic, where commercials **are not an obstacle**, they happen to part of a cultural phenomenon with many of those people -- there will be commercials on those.

> All in all, more stringent regulations at the state and local level **are not an obstacle** to the furtherance of Congress's purpose in creating Title VI.

> In addition, state and local statutes and ordinances typically **are not obstacles** to negotiating international agreements.